# TensorFlow lambda is adding one dimension if used with Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

If the TensorFlow Keras code is written in functional manner

```
input_positive = Input(shape=(input_size,), name="input_query")
x_positive = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(input_positive)
x_positive = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=None)(x_positive),  # No activation on final dense layer
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(x_positive)  # L2 normalize embeddings
self.model = Model(inputs=input_positive, outputs=output)
```

then the output's shape of model is `(1, None, 128)`. But if written sequentially:

```
self. model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu", input_shape=(input_size,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=None),  # No activation on final dense layer
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))  # L2 normalize embeddings
])
```

the output's shape of model is `(None, 128)`. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It's a typo... remove the comma after (x_positive) and before output layer in the functional format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able replicate your issue using sample input in functional model

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_positive = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="input_query")
x_positive = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(input_positive)
x_positive = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=None)(x_positive),  # No activation on final dense layer
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(x_positive)  # L2 normalize embeddings

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_positive, outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_query (InputLayer)     [(None, 1)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               256       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               16512     
_________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)              (1, None, 128)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 16,768
Trainable params: 16,768
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Fixed code:**

As rightly mentioned by @Marco Cerliani. You should remove `comma` at the end of the second dense layer (i.e, right after `(x_positive)`) or before the lambda layer (i.e, `output`).

```
input_positive = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="input_query")
x_positive = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(input_positive)
x_positive = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=None)(x_positive)  # No activation on final dense layer
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(x_positive)  # L2 normalize embeddings

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_positive, outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_query (InputLayer)     [(None, 1)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 128)               256       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 128)               16512     
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 128)               0         
=================================================================
Total params: 16,768
Trainable params: 16,768
Non-trainable params: 0
```